# An object with mass $m$ thrown with speed $v_0$. There is gravity and air resistance. Find the speed of the object right before it falls on the ground

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, projectile, drag

There is an object with mass $m$ on the ground. This object is being thrown with speed $v_0$. There is gravity and air resistance. The air resistance is given by $\vec{F}=-m\alpha\vec{v(t)}$ and $\alpha$ is a real constant. Find the speed of this object right before it falls down on the ground.

I choose the vertical axis as y-axis. Thus, $\vec{v(t)}=v(t)\hat{y}$.

$$\vec{F}_{net}=\vec{F}_{gravity}+\vec{F}_{resistance}$$

$$\vec{F}_{net}=-mg\hat{y}-m\alpha v(t)\hat{y}$$

$$\vec{F}_{net}=-m(g+\alpha v(t))\hat{y}$$

$$\vec{F}_{net}=m\vec{a} \Rightarrow \vec{a}=-(g+\alpha v(t))\hat{y}$$

$$\vec{a}=\frac{d\vec{v(t)}}{dt}=-(g+\alpha v(t))\hat{y}$$

$$\frac{dv(t)}{dt}=-(g+\alpha v(t))\Rightarrow \frac{dv}{g+\alpha v(t)}=-dt$$

$$\int_{v_0}^{v(t)}{\frac{dv}{g+\alpha v(t)}}=-\int_0^t{dt}$$

$$g+\alpha v(t)=u\Rightarrow dv(t)=\frac{du}{\alpha}$$

$$\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{v_0}^{v(t)}{\frac{du}{u}}=-t$$

$$\frac{1}{\alpha}\left[\ln(u)\right]_{v_0}^{v(t)}=-t\Rightarrow\frac{1}{\alpha}\left[\ln(g+\alpha v(t))\right]_{v_0}^{v(t)}=-t$$

$$\ln\left(\frac{g+\alpha v(t)}{g+\alpha v_0}\right)=-\alpha t$$

$$e^{\ln\left(\frac{g+\alpha v(t)}{g+\alpha v_0}\right)}=e^{-\alpha t}$$

$$\frac{g+\alpha v(t)}{g+\alpha v_0}=e^{-\alpha t}$$

$$v(t)=-\frac{g+\alpha v_0}{\alpha}e^{-\alpha t}-\frac{g}{\alpha}$$

I found $v(t)$ as shown above. The next step is to find $y(t)$ and it's roots. So I can find the time values where $y(t)=0$. There must be $t=0$ and another value which is time the object falls on the ground. By taking the integral of $v(t)$,

$$y(t)=-\frac{g+\alpha v_0}{\alpha^2}e^{-\alpha t}-\frac{g}{\alpha}t$$

$$-\frac{g+\alpha v_0}{\alpha^2}e^{-\alpha t}-\frac{g}{\alpha}t=0$$

$$\frac{g+\alpha v_0}{\alpha^2}e^{-\alpha t}=-\frac{g}{\alpha}t$$

$$te^{\alpha t}=-\frac{g+\alpha v_0}{g\alpha}$$

The first root is $t_1=0$. But I couldn't find the second root (I don't know if there is another). I shared my solution here. Can you check my solution and correct me, please?

Comment: So $t_1=0 \Rightarrow 0=\frac{g+\alpha v_0}{g\alpha}$?

Comment: @Gert Uhmm, that's not possible. Seems like something wrong with my calculus. Can you spot it?

Comment: It's possible for $v_0=-g/\alpha$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Your last equation is transcendental and can only be solved numerically.

Comment: FYI, I believe your derivation is correct up to your expression for $v(t)$.  I also believe that @Gert is correct that that you won't be able to find a closed-form expression for the value of $t$ (even after you correct your error.)

Comment: I think you dropped a minus sign in your expression for $y(t)$...

Comment: @Gert Yes, $v_o=-g/\alpha$ makes sense. But I still can't understand what's wrong with my solution. Or how can I find the speed of the object right before it falls on the ground.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Okay, thanks. Do you have any idea how I can find the speed of the object right before it falls on the ground?

Comment: When you integrated $v(t)$, you dropped the minus sign of $-\alpha$.

Comment: @Gert Oh, I just noticed that. Okay, I edited my question. But still not helpful for solving the question :(

Comment: My suggestion would be to start over and try to find a direct relationship between $v$ and $x$, rather than finding two separate relationships for $v$ vs. $t$ and $x$ vs. $t$ and trying to combine them.  Note that $dv/dt = (dv/dx) (dx/dt) = v (dv/dx)$.  That's about all I'm comfortable saying given the homework/check-my-work policy on this site.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Okay, thanks. I will try your advice and inform you if it solved my question.

Comment: You still have a negative sign error. You should go through the problem again with a clean sheet of paper and find it yourself. It's a good algebra exercise. Based on your result $v(0)$ is not $v_0$.

Comment: And for future reference, check my work questions are off-topic.

Comment: @BillN I couldn't spot where I have negative sign error. I tried to solve from scratch, but I still get the same result. Also, when I take the derivative of $v(t)$ that I found, I can't get $a(t)=-(g+\alpha v(t))$. It gives me $a(t)=-(g+\alpha v(t))e^{-at}$. Do you have any idea why I can't get the same acceleration function ($-(g+\alpha v(t))$) when I take the derivate of $v(t)$ fuction I found?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I found this expression: $v-\ln\left(\frac{g+\alpha v}{g+\alpha v_0}\right)^{g/\alpha}=v_0-\alpha^2 y$. I don't know how to solve this for $v(t)$ :(

Comment: Look at your expression for $v(t)$. If you plug in $t=0$ you don't get $v_0$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:  Your expression for $y(t)$ implies that $y(0) = (g+\alpha v_0)/\alpha^2$.  Is this what you intended?

Comment: Hmm, $y(0)$ should give me $0$. There's something wrong, right.